# Twitter Popup Login Window

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter, authentication

I'm currently trying to look at Twitter's code to see how they created their popup login window within the same page.  I wanted to know if anyone knew how to create something like this or could point me in different directions?  I've already tried using Google but with no real luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a tutorial: http://aext.net/2009/08/perfect-sign-in-dropdown-box-likes-twitter-with-jquery/ Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is commonly referred to as a **Lightbox**. There are many examples revealed through search engines.